# newtonsoft.json 9.0.1 not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 in newly created Visual Studio Project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I created a new ASP.NET Core Web Application in Visual Studio 2017 and immediately got the following error:

```
Restoring NuGet packages...
Package Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1 supports:
  - net20 (.NETFramework,Version=v2.0)
  - net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5)
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - netstandard1.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.0)
  - portable-net40+sl5+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile328)
  - portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259)
One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.
NuGet package restore failed.
```

It seems that Newtonsoft.Json is not compatible with netcoreapp, but why would VisualStudio include it if that is the case? I'm pretty new to ASP.NET so maybe there is something I am missing? I followed the steps from the [ASP.NET Core Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc).

While searching I found some similar issues, but none seem to be compatible with VS 2017.

Also here is my .csproj file if it helps:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: I created a new web app with the same `.csproj` and had no issues. The tooling is still a little rough around the edges. You may have run into a rare issue. Try running `dotnet restore` in the package manager console or through command prompt.

Comment: @TravisBoatman I tried it with the pkg manager console and the command prompt and it also gives the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just reinstalled Visual Studio, repaired it from the installer and cleared the NuGet Cache and now it's working. Seems like something wasn't setup correctly.